# Show Value instead of Text on selected option

Tags: html

is it possible to only show the value of a selection box, when something is selected

So, I have those as option and they get displayed, when the user is about to select an option with the long text

```
<option value="SHRT">SHRT (Short Value)</option>
<option value="SMTH">SMTH (Something goes here-Value)</option>
```

when an option is chosen, the box usually has the text "SHRT (Short Value)". Is there a way to get "SHRT" instead, but still be able to display the longtext upon selection?

thanks in advance